# GameDevelopment: Is there an equivalent to TexturePacker to optimize single images RGB format?

Tags: image, cocos2d-iphone, textures, texturepacker

Might be a silly question. I am using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to export texture sheets for my Cocos2d game.

At the end of certain levels I want to display a special image that tells the user that a new world is unlocked. I thought to create a single texture sheet in pvr.ccz RGB4444 format using some useful Dithering algorithm to optimize the alpha information in the image.

However I am wondering.. is this the best way to include an optimized image in the game? Or should I use GIMP/Photoshop etc.. to optimize and export it?

Comment: define "best". pvr.ccz is the smallest, fastest image format. PS and Gimp can't do pvr.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a way to export somethign similar to pvr.ccz with GIMP or Photoshop. I think the answer below is probably the best procedure to follow. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exporting image from TexturePacker is the best (and the simplest) way.
GIMP and Photoshop wont export to pvr.ccz.
Even simple images generated by Photoshop or GIMP, its better to add it to TexturePacker and export again.